# Tomcat server - This is a proxy server. Does not respond to non-proxy requests

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, server

I have created a tomcat server with thingworx and trying to open Tomcat but it is giving response like

> "This is a proxy server. Does not respond to non-proxy requests."

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Initially it was working fine. But, after some time it is showing like "This is a proxy server. Does not respond to non-proxy requests."